# An object is not showing in the rendered result

Tags: rendering, objects, outliner

I am very new to Blender and following the Blender Guru Donut tutorial from Youtube. 
My particles are showing in the final render but the emitter is missing.

I am positive that I have ticked that camera icon in the *Outliner* as shown in the above figure.

[image]

When I render however, the sprinkles which are hair particles on the icing are shown, but not the icing itself which is the emitter.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello :). You need to check *Show Emitter* in *Particle settings > Render > Show Emitter* :). (in the first screenshot it's visibly unchecked)

Comment: Oh, it solves it! Thank you and you should put it as an answer, I will check it.

Comment: Done :). This is actually a pretty regular question here. But the other threads aren't easy to find...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check Show Emitter through
*Particle settings > Render > Show Emitter*

[image]